# What is the purpose of EasyMock.andVoid()?

Tags: java, easymock

The javadoc for `EasyMock.andVoid()` read's as follows

> Records a call but returns nothing. Used to chain calls on void methods expectLastCall().andThrow(e).andVoid()
>
> **Returns**:
>
> this object to allow method call chaining.lockquote

Do you know any possible situation in which one needs this? What is the purpose of `andVoid()` in the above example?

Let us consider:

```
myMock.myMethod();
expectLastCall().andVoid().andThrow(e)
```

With `myMethod` having return type `void`. Then we could just omit the 'chain-element' `andVoid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really rare what you will need this. Because in most case you only need to call the void method to mock it. Like this

```
MyClass myMock = mock(MyClass.class);
myMock.myMethod();
replay(myMock);
myMock.myMethod(); // one call to myMethod expected
verify(myMock);
```

Which is a synonym of

```
MyClass myMock = mock(MyClass.class);
myMock.myMethod();
expectLastCall();
replay(myMock);
myMock.myMethod(); // one call to myMethod expected
verify(myMock);
```

Then let's say you want the first call to `myMethod` to throw an exception and the second to respond normally, you can do.

```
MyClass myMock = mock(MyClass.class);
myMock.myMethod();
expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException("test"));
expectLastCall().andVoid();
replay(myMock);
try {
  myMock.myMethod(); // one call to myMethod will throw an exception
  fail("should throw");
} catch(RuntimeException e) {}
myMock.myMethod(); // the other will be normal
verify(myMock);
```

Or by chaining them

```
MyClass myMock = mock(MyClass.class);
myMock.myMethod();
expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException("test")).andVoid();
replay(myMock);
try {
  myMock.myMethod(); // one call to myMethod will throw an exception
  fail("should throw");
} catch(RuntimeException e) {}
myMock.myMethod(); // the other will be normal
verify(myMock);
```

This use case is of course super rare but we still support it.

Comment: Just a small comment: Instead of 'expectLastCall().andVoid();' one could just write 'myMock.myMethod();'. Thus, the use of '.andVoid()' is not necessarily needed.

Comment: @Chris311 Yes. I know. It's there more for completude. And if you love chaining expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The [related API docs](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/internal/MocksControl.html#andVoid--) goes like this:

> Records a call but returns nothing. Used to chain calls on void
>   methods expectLastCall().andThrow(e).andVoid()

The point is to record a call. Later the [`verify`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/internal/MocksControl.html#verify--) call can check if this call has happened.